# Create unique id based on an id and timestamp difference

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have a table with following information:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(
    col1 bigint,
    col2 TIMESTAMP,
    col3 integer
)
```

Some sample data is

```
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:02:16+03"; 51
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:06:25+03"; 52
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:13:38+03"; 53
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:21:19+03"; 56
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:01:16+03"; 31
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:06:16+03"; 29
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:37:16+03"; 30
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:39:16+03"; 31
```

The values are sorted on col1 and col2 in ascending order. Now the requirement is to append a computed column at the end based on the conditions:

- the first row is given id 1
- from row 2 onwards if current col1 = col1 of previous row and current col2 - previous col2 < 30 then the id will be 1 (same as row 1) else increment id by 1.

So the output will be something like

```
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:02:16+03"; 51; 1
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:06:25+03"; 52; 1
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:13:38+03"; 53; 1
28564635; "2014-03-11 07:21:19+03"; 56; 1
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:01:16+03"; 31; 2
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:06:16+03"; 29; 2
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:37:16+03"; 30; 3
28564636; "2014-03-11 07:39:16+03"; 31; 3
```

How can I achieve this in SQL query without using cursors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/61e01/2)

Data:

```
-- drop table if exists table1;

create table table1(
    col1 bigint,
    col2 timestamp,
    col3 integer
);

insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3) values
   (28564635, '2014-03-11 07:02:16+03', 51),
   (28564635, '2014-03-11 07:06:25+03', 52),
   (28564635, '2014-03-11 07:13:38+03', 53),
   (28564635, '2014-03-11 07:21:19+03', 56),
   (28564636, '2014-03-11 07:01:16+03', 31),
   (28564636, '2014-03-11 07:06:16+03', 29),
   (28564636, '2014-03-11 07:37:16+03', 30),
   (28564636, '2014-03-11 07:39:16+03', 31)
;
```

Query:

```
select
  *,
  sum(test) over (order by col1, col2) as rn
from (
  select
    *,
    (not 
       coalesce(extract(epoch from col2 
       - lag(col2) over(partition by col1 order by col2))/60.0 < 30, false)
    )::int as test
  from
    table1
  ) a
```

Result:

```
28564635;2014-03-11 07:02:16;51;1;1
28564635;2014-03-11 07:06:25;52;0;1
28564635;2014-03-11 07:13:38;53;0;1
28564635;2014-03-11 07:21:19;56;0;1
28564636;2014-03-11 07:01:16;31;1;2
28564636;2014-03-11 07:06:16;29;0;2
28564636;2014-03-11 07:37:16;30;1;3
28564636;2014-03-11 07:39:16;31;0;3
```

Explanation:

1. Get previous `col2` for current `col1`
2. Substract current `col2` from previous `col2` and calculate number of minutes
3. Test if it is less then 30 minutes
4. Coalesce result to `false` (for rows with no previous `col2`)
5. Note: The previous will flag every first row (by `col1`) and every row where difference > 30 minutes with `false`
6. Negate everything - we get `true` for all rows where we would like to increment counter
7. Cast boolean to integer (`true=1`, `false=0`)
8. In outer query calculate running sum of our test, ordered by `col1` and `col2`